# Node Express session not working on live server/production

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Session is working not live server/ production but its working on local
below is my app.js config

```
app.enable('trust proxy',true);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sessions({
    secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
    saveUninitialized:true,
    cookie: { maxAge: twoDay,secure:false },
    resave: false 
}));
```

I have tried both `secure:false`  and `secure:true`  
below  is my Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 8088;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by Adding proxy: true in session config as bellow

```
app.enable('trust proxy',true);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sessions({
   proxy: true,
   secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
   saveUninitialized:true,
   cookie: { maxAge: twoDay,secure:false },
   resave: false 
}));
```